# How much of the jejunum is bypassed during gastric bypass?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, surgery

There is both long and short limb gastric bypass surgeries (along with several other variations on intestinal bypass procedures). How much of the jejunum is bypassed with a long-limb and short-limb gastric bypass?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most used surgical technique is Roux en-Y where the small intestine is divided approximately 40-50 cm below the lower stomach outlet and is re-arranged into a Y-configuration.

The portion of intestine (jejunum) from the upper stomach is called the "Roux limb". It has a total length of 80 - 150 cm.

So the Roux en-Y technique "bypasses" only the duodenum and a small portion of jejunum - no more than 50 cm, that's about 7-10% of total length of small intestine.

[image: Total gastrectomy with Roux-en-Y.png]
"[Total gastrectomy with Roux-en-Y](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Total_gastrectomy_with_Roux-en-Y.png#mediaviewer/File:Total_gastrectomy_with_Roux-en-Y.png)" by [ignis](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Ignis) - Own work. licensed [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

**Reference:** Wikipedia contributors, "Gastric bypass surgery," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gastric_bypass_surgery&oldid=606081291 (accessed June 27, 2014).